# Error with retrieveing records from Power Bi API Datasets - Get Refresh History

Tags: powershell, api, powerbi, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying get Refresh Logs for each dataset from Power BI rest API with Power Shell script.

Documentation for API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getrefreshhistory

But I'm getting below error in power shell. could you please help me ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight, you should use [Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.profile/invoke-powerbirestmethod?view=powerbi-ps) instead of the generic [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.1). The first one will take care of adding the authorization token in the request for you, which you must add manually when using the generic cmdlet (and you didn't).